# Substract column values of two rows based on Dense Rank

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which has the below data

```
srl_no      created_on              completed_on            prev_completed_on               time_from_last  Dense_Rank
XXXXXX1     2020-10-09T08:52:25     2020-10-09T08:57:45     null                            null            1
XXXXXX1     2020-10-09T09:04:32     2020-10-09T09:06:37     2020-10-09T08:57:45             407             2
XXXXXX1     2020-10-09T09:10:10     2020-10-09T09:12:17     2020-10-09T09:06:37             213             3
XXXXXX1     2020-10-09T09:10:10     2020-10-09T09:12:17     2020-10-09T09:12:17             -127            3
```

I want to substract the `prev_completed_on` from the `created_on` to get the `time_from_last` however as the last two rows have the same `created_on` and `completed_on` I am getting the time as negative. In this scenario I need to substract the value from the second row, i.e. substract based on the `dense_rank` column.

So in the above scenario I need to substract the value of `completed_on` of 2nd row from the value of `created_on` for the 4th row.

Code for the above

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('XXXXXX1','2020-10-09T08:52:25','2020-10-09T08:57:45'), # create your data here, be consistent in the types.
        ('XXXXXX1','2020-10-09T09:04:32','2020-10-09T09:06:37'),
        ('XXXXXX1','2020-10-09T09:10:10','2020-10-09T09:12:17'),
        ('XXXXXX1','2020-10-09T09:10:10','2020-10-09T09:12:17'),
    ],
    ['srl_no', 'created_on','completed_on'] # add your columns label here
)

df = df.withColumn('created_on',f.col('created_on').cast(TimestampType()))
df = df.withColumn('created_on',f.col('created_on').cast(TimestampType()))


partition_cols = ["srl_no"]
window_clause = Window.partitionBy(partition_cols).orderBy(f.col('completed_on').asc())
# create the row number column
df1 = df.withColumn('prev_completed_on',f.lag(f.col("completed_on"))\
                                                       .over(window_clause).cast(TimestampType()))
df1 = df1.withColumn('dense_rank',f.dense_rank()\
                                                       .over(window_clause))
df1 = df1.withColumn("time_from_last",\
                             f.col("created_on").cast(LongType()) - col("prev_completed_on").cast(LongType()))
```

expected output

```
srl_no      created_on              completed_on            prev_completed_on               time_from_last  Dense_Rank
XXXXXX1     2020-10-09T08:52:25     2020-10-09T08:57:45     null                            null            1
XXXXXX1     2020-10-09T09:04:32     2020-10-09T09:06:37     2020-10-09T08:57:45             407             2
XXXXXX1     2020-10-09T09:10:10     2020-10-09T09:12:17     2020-10-09T09:06:37             213             3
XXXXXX1     2020-10-09T09:10:10     2020-10-09T09:12:17     2020-10-09T09:12:17             **213**             3
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you are currently using?

Comment: @mpSchrader added the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to use a groupby to get the minimum date per `srl_no`, `dense_rank`. When joining that back to the prepared data frame you get the required result.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('XXXXXX1','2020-10-09T08:52:25','2020-10-09T08:57:45'), # create your data here, be consistent in the types.
        ('XXXXXX1','2020-10-09T09:04:32','2020-10-09T09:06:37'),
        ('XXXXXX1','2020-10-09T09:10:10','2020-10-09T09:12:17'),
        ('XXXXXX1','2020-10-09T09:10:10','2020-10-09T09:12:17'),
    ],
    ['srl_no', 'created_on','completed_on'] # add your columns label here
)

df = df.withColumn('created_on',F.col('created_on').cast(T.TimestampType()))
df = df.withColumn('created_on',F.col('created_on').cast(T.TimestampType()))


partition_cols = ["srl_no"]
window_clause = Window.partitionBy(partition_cols).orderBy(F.col('completed_on').asc())

# create the row number column
df_with_rank = df.withColumn('prev_completed_on',F.lag(F.col("completed_on"))\
                                                       .over(window_clause).cast(T.TimestampType()))
df_with_rank = df_with_rank.withColumn('dense_rank', F.dense_rank()\
                                                       .over(window_clause))

dense_rank = df_with_rank.groupby("srl_no", "dense_rank") \ 
                .agg(F.min('prev_completed_on').alias('prev_completed_on'))

df_with_rank = df_with_rank.drop('prev_completed_on')   
df_with_rank = df_with_rank.join(dense_rank, ["srl_no", "dense_rank"], 'left')     

df_with_rank.show()
```

**Output:**

```
+-------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| srl_no|dense_rank|         created_on|       completed_on|  prev_completed_on|
+-------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|XXXXXX1|         1|2020-10-09 08:52:25|2020-10-09T08:57:45|               null|
|XXXXXX1|         2|2020-10-09 09:04:32|2020-10-09T09:06:37|2020-10-09 08:57:45|
|XXXXXX1|         3|2020-10-09 09:10:10|2020-10-09T09:12:17|2020-10-09 09:06:37|
|XXXXXX1|         3|2020-10-09 09:10:10|2020-10-09T09:12:17|2020-10-09 09:06:37|
+-------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```